# Dynamic Ref Keys in React

Tags: reactjs, webpack

I swear I have been all over Google trying to find the solution to this, but have not found a good answer yet, so I apologize if this is a noob question.

I am building an app with React.js and all has been great.  However, we started moving toward production bundling and all hell broke loose. I chased the error to the refs that we dynamically name in loops.  For example:

```
render() {
  // ...
  ["foo", "bar", "baz"].map(i => {
    return <SomeComponent ref={`item-${i}`}/>
  })
}
```

The mind-bender is that this works in unoptimized React.  No errors are logged in the console.  However, when using the production build of React, it gives me an error, pointing to https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/error-decoder.html?invariant=120.

I have been able to remove refs that have dynamic keys elsewhere, but in a handful of cases, I need to maintain the references in order to use them later.  So, what is the "proper" way to do this, and why would this work with different builds of react?

**NOTES**

Here's what we have in our stack which may be relevant.:

- ES6 syntax, transpiled
- React 15.1.0 (tried with the most recent version and the issue persists)
- Redux state management
- Immutable.js
- Grunt
- Webpack (compiles app as well as React from source, and uglifies it)

Comment: 10 out of 10 times this error is caused by multiple copies of React being loaded. Usual suspect: you split your application in two bundles; libs.js and app.js (or something else), and somehow both contain React.

Comment: In case you don't find a solution, it's worth mentioning that there's probably a better solution than refs to whatever you're doing. Perhaps your data is flowing in the wrong direction. If you're doing things "the React way", you should almost never have to use refs - and even if you do, it's probably to target DOM elements, not React components. So you might consider refactoring your code to get rid of refs.

Comment: @dannyjolie I had it split, but combining them again did not solve it.

Comment: @matis-lepik I get your point, but sometimes, for UI purposes, its nice to have a reference to an element in order to do things like, get it's position on screen, and what not.

Comment: @AaronWagner That's definitely true (although some "hardcore" react users might insist that there's a better way to solve those problems with React as well). However, in this case, you're adding a ref to a React component, not to a DOM element. If you need to select an element by traveling down nested component refs, things have the potential to get real confusing real fast.